# Device ID with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, imei, deviceid

I would like to extract the IMEI number/Device ID from the computer using excel.

In CMD I can do it in this way: :netsh mbn sh interface" and from the list given I take the Device ID.

I was tryong to find something online but no luck so far, that's why I'm asking your help, maybe some of you knows where to search or how to start.

How can I do this with excel vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following and then use split function to extract what you need

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TEST()
   Debug.Print CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /V /C netsh mbn show interface").StdOut.ReadAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Thank you. I only had time to try it out today. Thank you once more.